# Get the first three column of a pyspark RDD row

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, rdd

I have a source data set which the data is in .dat format. the sample data will be like this

1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama
5::Father of the Bride Part II (1995)::Comedy
6::Heat (1995)::Action|Crime|Thriller

I created rdd of this and i split it by ("::"). I need to pull out a new rdd from it which contain only first two rows. like below

1   Toy Story (1995)
2   Jumanji (1995)
3   Grumpier Old Men (1995)
4   Waiting to Exhale (1995)
5   Father of the Bride Part II (1995)
6   Heat (1995)

please suggest me  way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a map:

```
rdd = sc.textFile('inputfile.dat')
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split("::")[:2])
# additionally you can join them back together
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: " ".join(x))
```